# AVSpeechUtterance: how to fetch a random array and use a specific voice?

Tags: swift, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

While working at using Swift to spew forth quotations, I'm running into issues with the repetition of the same command.

Here's what I have right now

```
import AVFoundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let QuoteArray = [
"Quote1",
"Quote2",
"Quote3",
]

let max = QuoteArray.count

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: QuoteArray[Int.random(in: 0 ... max)])
utterance.rate = 0.5
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-AU")
synthesizer.speak(AVSpeechUtterance(string: QuoteArray[Int.random(in: 0 ... max)]))
sleep(5)
synthesizer.speak(AVSpeechUtterance(string: QuoteArray[Int.random(in: 0 ... max)]))
sleep(10)
synthesizer.speak(AVSpeechUtterance(string: QuoteArray[Int.random(in: 0 ... max)]))
```

I'm not sure how to both pick a random array position, and to fool around with the synthesisvoice and speed. I'm trying to make it so that 3 random quotes are read randomly, yet I can't seem to get it to work properly.

If I modify the last few lines so  instead of `AVSpeechUtterance(string...`they say `utterance`, I cannot run a 2nd or 3rd quote because of a `SIGBART` error.

Any ideas?

```
utterance.rate = 35
utterance.pitchMultiplier = 3
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-AU")
synth.speak(utterance)
sleep(5)
synth.speak(utterance)
sleep(10)
synth.speak(utterance)
sleep(15)
```

if i try to bring it back to these utterances, i get a

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation."
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to both pick a random array position...

Hereunder a solution for your problem *(swift 5.0, iOS 12)* tested in a playground blank project:

```
    import AVFoundation
    import UIKit

    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    let QuoteArray = ["Quote1",
                      "Quote2",
                      "Quote3"]

    func newRandomUtterance() -> AVSpeechUtterance {

        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: QuoteArray[Int.random(in: 0..<QuoteArray.count)])
        utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")

        return utterance
     }

    for _ in 1...3 { synthesizer.speak(newRandomUtterance()) }
```

> ... and to fool around with the synthesisvoice and speed.

There are a [detailed summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18236.html) of the WWDC 2018 video dealing with the speech synthesizer and a [full explanation with code snippets](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis) *(ObjC and Swift)* that can help if the example above isn't enough.

You will now be able to **fetch a random array and use a specific voice**.